# Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly #42072

Tags: flutter, dart

No flutter commands seem not to work on the terminal..I always get a crash report when I try to run flutter. I have tried several flutter commands but I am getting the same below report.

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 351c1d27593c06ff)
Crash report written to C:\Users\Gyasi\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_17.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

**LOG FILE**

Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

flutter help

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: writeFrom failed, path = 'C:\Users\Gyasi\Documents\TUT\FLUTTER\flutter\version' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)

```
#0      _RandomAccessFile.writeFrom.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:856:9)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#3      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#6      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)
#7      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:513:7)
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#12     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#13     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#14     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

### flutter doctor

```
[32m[✓][39m Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1040], locale en-US)
    [32m•[39m Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at C:\Users\Gyasi\Documents\TUT\FLUTTER\flutter
    [32m•[39m Framework revision 20e59316b8 (3 months ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    [32m•[39m Engine revision fee001c93f
    [32m•[39m Dart version 2.4.0

[32m[✓][39m Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    [32m•[39m Android SDK at C:\Users\Gyasi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    [32m•[39m Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    [32m•[39m Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    [32m•[39m ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Gyasi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    [32m•[39m Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    [32m•[39m Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    [32m•[39m All Android licenses accepted.

[32m[✓][39m Android Studio (version 3.1)
    [32m•[39m Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    [32m•[39m Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
    [32m•[39m Dart plugin version 173.4700
    [32m•[39m Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[32m[✓][39m VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.38.1)
    [32m•[39m VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    [32m•[39m Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[33m[!][39m Connected device
    [32m•[39m Device 26EBB18325159243 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

[33m![39m Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Try following the official docs on installing flutter. If you are unable to run flutter commands this is likely because you did not run flutter.bat script file and did not add the flutter/bin folder to environment variables

Comment: You can give the progress here if you are successful

Comment: Please mention the result of `flutter doctor`

Comment: @Taio every command is failing including flutter doctor. Everything has been working fine since the day install the dart SDK.. I have build  3 Apps with the same setup...

Comment: @pasanbuddhika  flutter doctor is giving me the same error report

Answer (score 1):

If it says "Access denied" it might be because you installed it with admin privilieges. Try deleting your current install of Flutter and re-installing it following the [official guide from the doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) and check if the folder has correct permissions.